# Confidence Interval for Non Linear Regression Model

Tags: r, nls

My data consist of two columns: time and cumulative number like below:

```
time <- c(1:14)
cum.num <- c(20, 45, 99, 195, 301, 407, 501, 582, 679, 753, 790, 861, 1011, 1441)
```

My non linear function is:

```
c1*cos(0.6731984259*time)+c2*sin(0.6731984259*time)+c3*(time)^2+c4*time+c5
```

My objective is to model this function using non linear regression using `nls()` in R and to compute the confidence interval. I have donr the following:

```
m1.fit<-nls(cum.vul~c1*cos(0.6731984259*time)+c2*sin(0.6731984259*time)+c3*(time)^2+c4*time+c5,start=list(c1=-50,c2=-60,c3=5,c4=8,c5=100))
```

I got an error while computing confidence interval, i have tried the following:

```
confint(m1.fit)
```

Once i issued this command got the following error:

> ```
> Waiting for profiling to be done...
> Error in prof$getProfile() : 
> step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
> ```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try package nlstools:

```
> nlstools::confint2(m1.fit)
         2.5 %     97.5 %
c1  -48.556270  54.959689
c2 -175.654079 -45.216965
c3    3.285062   9.529072
c4  -49.254627  46.007629
c5  -34.135835 272.864743`
```

Comment: nlstools::confint2 produces Wald confidence intervals, yes?
Be cautious with using that if the distribution of your parameter is skewed.